# Replacing database with another database at runtime.

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two databases, one database is the primary. This primary DB is responsible for holding the current data which is up to date and my secondary DB is populated via a cron job, once the primary DB gets obsolete I want to replace it with the secondary DB via a file operation of just over writing the existing DB and refreshing my views. Is it possible to do this, is there a better way?

So far what I have done is:

```
public void writeToSD() throws IOException {
        File f=new File("/mnt/sdcard/dump.db");
        FileInputStream fis=null;
        FileOutputStream fos=null;

        try{
            fis=new FileInputStream(f);


            fos=new FileOutputStream("/data/data/com.one.two/databases/Bdr");
            while(true){
                int i=fis.read();
                if(i!=-1){
                    fos.write(i);
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }
            fos.flush();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        finally{
            try{
                fos.close();
                fis.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioe){
                System.out.println(ioe);
            }
        }
```

Comment: why does the primary db get obsolete, if it is up to date?  what's the reason to change to the second db?

Comment: The primary DB gets obsolete every five minutes. The data values change!

Comment: And why do you not update the primary database on the fly?

Comment: Because I am inserting atleast 20000 records at a go!! in three different tables, it takes a lifetime!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about always using the same database files (let's say dbA, dbB) with two instances of SQLiteOpenHelper and using an utility class like this instead of using raw SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
class Db {
  private SQLiteOpenHelper mPrimaryDb;
  private SQLiteOpenHelper mSecondaryDb;

  public Db(Context context) {
    mPrimaryDb = new MyDbHelper(context, "db_a");
    mSecondaryDb = new MyDbHelper(context, "db_b");
  }

  public SQLiteOpenHelper getPrimaryDb() {
    return mPrimaryDb;
  }

  public SQLiteOpenHelper getSecondaryDb() {
    return mSecondaryDb;
  }

  public void swapDb() {
    SQLiteOpenHelper tmp = mPrimaryDb;
    mPrimaryDb = mSecondaryDb;
    mSecondaryDb = tmp;
    // TODO: notify data users that data has changed, cleanup the old primary database, etc.
  }
{
```

Comment: This idea seems great, however I have used transactions now. They speed up my batch inserts. I will definitely give this a try too!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use file operations, renaming the data base files is faster. But during file operations  all connections have to be closed before any action.

If insertion is too slow, I would not overwrite the database file. I would generate the new database with a temp name and the same table and view structure. After finishing writing to the temp file I would rename the file to the same name as the invariant part of the old database plus a version number or a timestamp . And in my application I would look periodically for a new version, if found I would close all connections to the old file and open the new database.